# Alternative word of extensive/broader experience

Tags: phrase-requests

I usually see "I have extensive experience" or "I have broader experience" in resume. I want to know an alternative way to express that "I have much experience and great knowledge in something"

Comment: Extensive is the way to go. "I have extensive experience in X"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually say "extensive knowledge" about something, but you could also say "comprehensive" knowledge or experience, or perhaps "considerable" experience or knowledge.

It also helps to know the subject at hand, because there are certain descriptive words that can be used within different industries that signify your knowledge and understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Expert? Expertise?

Though as I've understood from employers, these are fluff words that should be used sparingly; you should describe what you've done as opposed to what you think it makes you.

Answer (score 4):

According to [LinkedIn data](http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20101214005059/en/LinkedIn-Overused-Buzzwords-%E2%80%9CExtensive-Experience-Innovative-Motivated%E2%80%9D#.VVWai46qqko), the term *extensive experience* comes first in the top ten overused words in résumés across the United States:

1. **extensive experience** 2. *innovative* 3. *motivated* 4. *results-oriented* 5. *dynamic* 6. *proven track record* 7. *team player* 8. *fast-pacer* 9. *problem solver* 10. *entrepreneurial*

> said Lindsey Pollak, a career and workplace expert. “*If you’re using any of these 10 terms, wipe them out. Instead, note that you **have eight to ten years of experience** or that you increased sales by 300 percent. Include meaningful phrases that apply specifically to highlights you’ve achieved in your career.”*

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=broad%20experience%2Cextensive%20experience%2Cconsiderable%20experience%2Ca%20lot%20of%20experience&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbroad%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextensive%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsiderable%20experience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20lot%20of%20experience%3B%2Cc0) set on the American English Corpus confirms this trend. The following expressions are: *broad experience* (blue line); *extensive experience* (red line); *considerable experience* (green line) and *a lot of experience* (yellow).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try the word Cognoscente !

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).